# 21.5" iMac Mid 2010 Won't Boot from USB to Install High Sierra

Tags: imac, usb, startup, install, bootable-disk

I tried clean installing High Sierra in by making bootable USB. I did the following:

1. PRAM Reset
2. Pressed Option Key at the Startup
3. Choose USB with Install High Sierra from the Drives
4. The Apple logo screen appears and stays endlessly

I thought the USB might be corrupt so used different USB with light indicator and made bootable version of the High Sierra but same thing happens and after selecting install High Sierra the screen with Apple logo appears endlessly. The USB only lits up during the drive selection time and momentarily after Apple logo appears and then the light of the USB stays off indicating the iMac is not reading the USB.

Is this related to bad motherboard?

---

Log info as suggested by @At0mic & @Allan

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling macOS High Sierra from Internet Recovery or macOS Recovery? This would be the easiest way to proceed.

Comment: @Todd The HDD I entered is blank and needs proper partitioning. So I am not sure if I can use Recovery option

Comment: Have you tried Internet Recovery? This downloads the macOS Recovery image from the Internet so it might let you into macOS Recovery that way.

Comment: @Todd I tried pressing Command+R during startup but nothing happens. Is it what you are suggesting or there is another way?

Comment: Try holding Shift-Option-Command-R or Option-Command-R. Refer to this for further information. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: Alright. I do recall that I did these options as well. But I shall try again. If this doesnt work do we have alternative option?

Comment: You can try pressing and holding 'D' to start the Apple Diagnostics test. This does a basic check and might tell you if the USB ports aren't working.

Comment: Allright will try running diagnostics.

Comment: If internet recovery doesn't work, also try booting from the USB and immediately holding down cmd-v, as this will show you the log as you boot.

Comment: @At0mic somehow, the imac is not doing any of the recovery or diagnostic thing by holding 'D' on startup or holding 'Shift-Option-Command' or 'Option-Command-R'. Only 'Alt' option is working. Also the keyboard keys seems fine. Maybe the BIOS gone bad or something.

Comment: @gfdsal the D key won't work, as you need an install of macOS with the appropriate diagnostics software installed. Did you try the cmd-V yet? What does it display?

Comment: Your iMac doesn’t  support Internet recovery, nor does it have onboard diagnostics.  You’re not seeing any results from those actions because they were implemented in the years after your iMac was released.  See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313

Comment: @At0mic I have updated the log in the question.

Comment: No errors, but you’re right at the cusp of where it switches to the GUI (graphics mode).  I’m more convinced now that it’s your GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this related to bad motherboard?

Basically, yes.

You’ve got some good diagnostic information from attempting to boot from a USB installer.  If both your internal drive and the new USB installer have the exact same symptoms, the problem is with your computer itself.

Now, this particular vintage iMac had a removable GPU “card” and chances are (based on my professional experience), this is likely the case; these would often fail.  To get further confirmation, having a look at the boot messages ([Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) - hold <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> while booting) will help determine this.  Also, booting to the diagnostic disk that came with your Mac would allow you to run the graphics tests.

Can you replace it?

Absolutely.  Unlike 2012 and newer iMac computers that have the display assembly glued in place, the 2009-2011 models used magnets and Torx screws to hold it in place.  User servicing is definitely doable here.  [IFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2389+GPU+Card+Replacement/6272) has excellent repair instructions.

However, these are quite “expensive” and very rare as the 27” iMac was much more popular.  A cursory search on eBay found only one at over $100USD at the time of this writing. Is it worth fixing?  IMO, no.  It’s obsolete and no matter how much effort you put into it, it will only become more difficult to maintain.  However, if you’re into “retro computing,” this may be something you don’t want to give up on just yet.

Now, it could still be your logic board, but I think it’s unlikely (the probability isn’t zero).  The nice thing with eBay now, is that you get 30 days to return even on used products.  So, your risk is very low if it turns out not to be the GPU.

Comment: I have updated the boot log in my question.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is GPU problem? The graphics appear to be fine. Also I quite didnt understand what you meant by `No errors, but you’re right at the cusp of where it switches to the GUI (graphics mode). I’m more convinced now that it’s your GPU`

Comment: I am also confused, should GPU problem prevent OSX from booting from the USB?

Comment: Yes.  Both the USB installer and a full installation use a graphical interface. The fact its failing on the USB tells you its got nothing to do with macOS installed on your machine.

Comment: Thanks Allan. So shall I close the case and call it most likely bad GPU and less likely bad Logic board? There are no vertical lines or any artifacts on the display though, more over the light indicator in the USB turns off just few moments after selecting boot from USB.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “close the case;” we’re a Q/A site, not Tech Support.  GPU issues manifest in many different ways; vertical lines and artifacts are just two of them.  A dead GPU isn’t going to show anything.  Bad memory on the GPU may cause a kernel panic, etc.  The light in the USB just indicates activity with it.  No light, no activity.

Comment: I see. By closing the case I meant being convinced that I have resolve the issue and its most likely GPU issue. I didnt mean anything bad. I was actually planning on taking the harddrive with installed OSX from the 2010 imac 27", (which you helped me troubleshoot earlier). But after reading your answer I shouldnt take the trouble of removing the HDD from that one to this.

Comment: No, nothing bad inferred or implied.  Many people think this is Apple tech support.  I wouldn't go though the trouble unless you’ve got a replacement GPU or you intend to part it out and sell on eBay as funds fora new machine

Comment: Allan, after revisiting your answer, I realized you mentioned "Booting from Diagnostic Disk" I searched for a while and found diagnostic disks in .dmg format [iMac11,3 Mac-F2238BAE](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest). Will this be sufficient to know for sure all the faults in the system I have?

Comment: It should be.  The older diagnostics were much more useful than the newer utilities Apple provides.

Comment: Perfect! Make so much sense now.

Comment: Allright, I did perform the AHT as you suggested as got this code 4MEM/4/40000000: 0xbcb3f798. Does this mean anything useful. I cant get exact code listed anywhere by googling.

Comment: 4MEM refers to memory.  You don’t have a memory “door” like the 27” models, but you can do this DIY.  If you’re not adverse to opening up your iMac (the glass is held in with magnets and the LCD with torx screws), you can swap out the memory modules to see which one is bad.

Comment: Allright. I hope it is indeed the ram issue because it's lot easy to solve. Thnx a lot Allan

Comment: I'm hoping it is memory as well, because it's a very easy and inexpensive fix.